# tabs in an activity calling another different activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have 2 tabs in an activity, and i want to add a new tab and add a google map, so i need to create an activity that extends mapactivity. so far so good.
but i don't know how to call the activity just when the tab is chosen so the map could be shown.

this is my code

TabHost tabhost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
        tabhost.setup();

```
    TabSpec spec1 = tabhost.newTabSpec("tab1");
    spec1.setContent(R.id.tab1); 

    TabSpec spec2 = tabhost.newTabSpec("tab2");
    spec2.setContent(R.id.tab2);

    TabSpec spec3 = tabhost.newTabSpec("map");
    spec3.setContent(R.id.tab3);

    tabhost.addTab(spec1);
    tabhost.addTab(spec2);
    tabhost.addTab(spec3);
```

tab 1 and tab 2 are working as the code is all in the same activity.

any help?

Answer (score 1):

I have heard of [MapView](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView.html) and [MapFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment.html) but i am not sure what you mean by MapActivity - may be that's a custom activity someone gave you. But anyways, i would suggest you create a MapView or MapFragment and return that when the user clicks on the Map-Tab in your application. You don't have to trigger another activity to show the map screen. Use `spec3.setContent(MapViewInstance)` or `spec3.setContent(MapFragmentInstance)` to achieve what you need. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

```
    tabSpec=tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1");
    tabSpec.setIndicator("CLASS A");
    Intent i=new Intent(this,ClassA.class);
    tabSpec.setContent(i);
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

   tabSpec=tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2");
    tabSpec.setIndicator("CLASS B");
    Intent i=new Intent(this,ClassB.class);
    tabSpec.setContent(i);
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should work with `Fragments` instead of `Activities` to achieve this.
For pre-Honeycomb devices there is a compatibility API to use `Fragments`.

With `Fragments` you can use `FragmentTransation` to switch to the google map within the same `Tab`.

Comment: I am using honeycomb. is that a problem? and can you give me a sample code? and do i have to change all the code as it is already nearly ready. I just need to add this tab with google maps.

Comment: If you are using honeycomb, you can use Fragments.
I think you 'should' use fragments if you are developing for honeycomb or later.
[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) is some info to get started using fragments.